# PHP - Datetime bug -1 hour from 0am till 1am

Tags: php, datetime, diff

I want to make a timer website and for that i used the datetime from php.
First of all my code, how i use the datetime to calculate the time between now and my target date.

```
 $timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
 $now = new DateTime("now", $timezone); // aktuelle Uhrzeit/Datum
 $target_date = new DateTime($game_release["release_date"], $timezone);
 $interval = $now->diff($target_date);
```

So now that it is. If i want the hours i write

```
$interval->h;
```

so you should see i use it correctly. All of the calculations are working, but from 0am till 1am i recognized a bug.

It displays -1 hours! If it is 1am (or later) all is fine again.
The -1 hours bug occures really strange... .

For example:
1 year and 2 months, no bug!
1 year and 3 months, bug.
1 year and 4 months, bug.
1 year and 5 months, bug.
1 year and 6 months, bug.
1 year and 7 months, bug.
8 months 2 days = bug
8 months 22 days = no bug!

for my bad it is now 1am and the bug is away and all works fine again. It's really annoying... .

Can anyone help me to fix this?
I really think that this is a datetime bug... .

i still think it is a bug, but for me it doesn't matter anymore, in case of that i wrote a own timer function which is 100% exactly and don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

$interval->h just gives you part of the breakdown. For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$interval = date_create('now')->diff(date_create("Jan 1 2014"));
print_r($interval);
```

returns

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 6
    [d] => 23
    [h] => 2
    [i] => 29
    [s] => 11
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 204
)
```

Which means it's 6 months, 23 days, 2 hours, 2 hours, 29 minutes, and 11 seconds (negative) from the difference. OR it's 204 days (negative) away. If you want hours, you'll need to calculate or convert from this format to hours. This might get a bit complicated as you'd need to determine the number of days in each month between the dates.

It would be easier to use unix timestamps, I'd say, as those are in seconds, and just involve dividing by 60 for hours:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$today = time();
$targetdate = strtotime("Jan 1 2015");
echo (($targetdate-$today) /60);
echo " hours left";
```

Comment: i know that this is only a part of it. I have a timer website, so i use the year/s as well as the month/s and so even the seconds will be used for the timer ;-). But if nobody is able to fix the -1 hours bug i have to calculate the time, with the help of the function strtotime and so on.